# Is it possible to determine which input led to which output through shapely's union?

Tags: python, shapely

I have a collection of four line segments which cross one another:

[image: four lines crossing one another]

Using shapely's [`union` method](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.union), I can split these intersecting lines into a larger collection of shorter line segments which share common vertices:

[image: split line segments]

I'd like to be able to map these shorter line segments back to the larger line segment from which they originally came.

Is it possible to tag the input line segments in such a way that `union` will preserve the tag? And, if not, what's the most efficient way to map the shorter segments back to the originals?

Comment: You could intersect your points with the original line segments to find which ones they lie on. Not the most efficient but probably not too time-consuming. I don't know if union can return the sources; the docs should have some info.

Comment: @Jon I did wind up looking for `within` relationships between the inputs and outputs, which is N^2 without indexing. I found nothing in the shapely docs about the sources.

Comment: I use shapely within geopandas usually, so the index of the intersecting features is returned in a geodataframe and it's easy to do the mapping you want. So I feel confident you can do it efficiently with shapely, I'm just not sure exactly how. I think you'd want intersects(), not within(). What happens if you use the intersects() method with the points and line segments?

Comment: I do want `within` since I'm looking for overlapping line segments, not points. The N^2 check is fine for now, but if someone has a better solution I'd love to see it.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how you use union() to break apart the line segments!

Comment: `union` will take complex / self-intersecting geometries and produce simple ones. So this comes out for free if you iterate over the edges in the union.